# How to automatically update frames in xcode?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

In xcode whenever I add certain constrains, I need to manually click on update frames for the storyboard to properly reflect it. Is there any setting that I can change in xcode so that it automatically update frames every time you edit a constraint?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it won't update frames if the constraints don't yet fully specify the frame. In this case, because the constraints are incomplete, they show up in red:

[image]

Because these constraints are incomplete, edits to them will not result in frame updates (probably because it is ambiguous and it doesn't know where the frame should be).

But if you complete the constraints (and update the frame, if necessary), the constraints now appear in blue:

[image]

Once they're complete, subsequent edits to the constraints will immediately result in the change in frame.

Finally, it's worth remembering that if you're adding constraints via the popover window, there is a "Update frames" option right there in the popover, so you don't have to update them in a separate step:

[image]

Bottom line, if you have fully defined constraints with a frame that reflects those current constraints, any subsequent edits to the constraints *will* cause the frame to be automatically updated.